# Weird artefacts with baked normals

Tags: normal-map

I get this weird normal map when I bake from high poly sculpt to lower poly retopologized mesh created with Retopoflow 2.0. 
No area or angle stretch is present in those areas so I have no idea what the cause might be.
Has anybody experienced this before?

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: Check the normals on the faces of those artifacts, also check if the retopo mesh is overlapping the high-res mesh

Comment: It seems to happen where two parts of your mesh get close to each other so you should try to lower the "distance" field in the "bake" tab. I'll give a more detailed answer if it works

Comment: @AnthoJack Indeed it does make it better, if I fiddle around with they "ray distance" setting, I can make the artefacts almost disappear, but not quite. At that point whether I increase/decrease distance the artefacts worsen.

Also if I bake in Blender Render the process seems to work fine, but I would still like a solution for the Cycles engine if possible.

So far the solution you provided is the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When baking, you can imagine it (I'm not sure this is how the process actually works but seeing it that way seems to make sense) as if rays where cast from everywhere on your low poly mesh where a pixel from your texture is applied. This ray travels a certain distance (determined by the "distance" field in the "bake" tab) and everytime it meets another polygon, it analyses it and stores the desired values in the pixel it comes from.
 However, if it meets more than one polygon, it tries to store both values at once in a pixel that can only store on value which results in the artifact that you are seeing.
 Reducing the distance field should solve at least part of that problem. If your problem persists, you may want to consider using a cage but I'm not familiar with this feature, you'll have to find a tutorial on that yourself.
P.S.: A normal map is a normal map. Wether you made it in Cycles or Blender internal makes very little difference so if it seems to work for you in one better than the other, feel free to bake in that renderer and then use it in the other.
(Here again I'm no expert so if someone wants to correct me, you're welcome to do so)
Hope this helped